# VS 2010 Database ORM Plugin

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I am a c# business developer, not a DBA nor a Database Developer. I have fair notions & skills, but I love straightforward tools to unburden the load of simple database modeling and creating quick c# DALs so I can focus on business logic.
I have been using [Telerik ORM](http://www.telerik.com/products/orm.aspx) and [AgileFX ORM](http://www.agilefx.org/docs/using-modeling-tools/) (pic below)
Both have nice VS2010 plugins, but the first is not free, and the latter is not actively maintained, and has some weird annoying modeling bugs from time to time (though it fits exactly my plain-and-simple needs)

What free easy plug-and-play tools would you advice that could meet my expectations ?
I am using SQL Server, DB Scheme is already set. I just need to import & create a Data Access Layer for it.

[image]

**Edit :**
 As pointed out by an answer, I feel a bit stupid using Tier Application when there are built-in tools as Linq-to-SQL. Nice tutorial [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/224102-linq-to-sql-primer/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entity Framework and Linq-to-SQL are both built into Visual Studio.

Comment: And what about performance ? I have read many posts claiming that LINQ-to-SQL was pretty slow...

Comment: I've found L2S is faster than EF in my applications, but both are fast enough.

Comment: I was pretty satisfied. Did not try it yet in hardcore conditions, but it is fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

Telerik OpenAccess ORM actually has a [free version](http://www.telerik.com/products/orm/free.aspx) that you can use with SQL Server (and many other databases) with almost no limitations.

For the most part you shouldn't see any differences.

Comment: Wow, you're right ! I will give it another shot. I used it in 2010 but back then there were far more limitations to the free version ! It sound like it's a nice alternative today (though L2S good be far enough for basic uses)